# Is it possible to restart the server using WinSCP?

Tags: putty, winscp

I transferred the files from my local computer to the remote directory using WinSCP, but I'm curious if I can restart/reboot the server using the same application or i need to do that using PuTTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you can. WinSCP is a SFTP client, SFTP its a subsystem of SSH, but that does not mean that you can achieve everything you can do with SSH.

Here’s a complete list of commands supported by the SFTP protocol -> https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sftp/#sec-SFTP-Protocol

As you can see there’s no such ‘reboot’ instruction nor anything similar.

**EDIT**

As other answer says, WinSCP has the ability to issue remote commands https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command

So you can do `Commands > Open Terminal` and issue a `reboot`

Comment: You are right that it is not possible to do this with SFTP. But WinSCP is not SFTP client only. So it is possible actually. See my answer.

Comment: I see, you're right you can do https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command with it

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP has [Console window](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_console), where you can execute most shell commands. The only limitation is that the command must not require terminal emulation. What command like `reboot` typically do not.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need putty to do it.

Long answer: If you know what you are doing you could have a watch of some kind and reboot the server if you copy a special file (via WinSCP) to the server, I would strongly advise against this.
If you use putty to do this you should be aware that the system user root is most likely forbidden to log in via ssh directly. So you have to use putty with some other user and use su/sudo to reboot.

Answer (score -2):

To reboot a linux server
putty
sudo reboot